# Calculus problem profit of a bakery

Tags: calculus, derivatives, applications

Hello guys I have little background on this, I don't know how to attack this problem since I don't know what a "function of benefits" is or how to decide if it generate profits.

I know that if $f$ (of one variable) is non decreasing and positive, then it could be understood as generating profit and to do that I can take the deriva tive and if it is positive then $f$ is non decreasing, how ever I do not know what to do in this case, can you help me?

Any hint or reference would be appreciated.

"A bakery is triying to increase its market share by selling 3 different kinds of bread $A,B,C$ according to a market study, the benefits of this strategy are determined by the function $f(x,y,z)=2xy+2xz+2yz$ where $x,y,z$ are the number of sold units of $A,B,C$"

a) Would this model generate profits?\

b) If not, consider bread C is not produced, and the number of breads A,B 
is the same. Would it generate profits?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to figure out if $f\gt 0$.

Comment: I agree, this is not clear.  If you make one of each sort you get $6$ "benefits", whatever that might mean.  For a fixed sum (of $A+B+C$) you could show that you optimize $f$ by making all three equal, though that doesn't appear to be what is being asked.

Comment: Hi John, assuming I sell at least one bread $f>0$ I have no garantee of that...

Comment: Hoe do benefits relate to profits?